# Format numbers in tbl_summary gtsummary r

Tags: r, gtsummary

**Problem:**

I want to format big numbers in a categorical tbl_summary to simplify zeros.

**Reprex:**

```
data<-
  data.frame(variable1 = rep(1:4, each = 10000)) %>%
  mutate(
    variable1 =
      case_when(
        variable1 %in% 1 ~ "Dog",
        variable1 %in% 2 ~ "Cat",
        variable1 %in% 3 ~ "Lion",
        variable1 %in% 4 ~ "Tiger"
      )
  )

data %>% 
  tbl_summary()
```

**Output:**

| **Characteristic** | **N = 40,000** |
| --- | --- |
| variable1 |  |
| Cat | 10,000 (25%) |
| Dog | 10,000 (25%) |
| Lion | 10,000 (25%) |
| Tiger | 10,000 (25%) |

**Desired output:**

| **Characteristic** | **N = 40** |
| --- | --- |
| variable1 | Results in thousands |
| Cat | 10 (25%) |
| Dog | 10 (25%) |
| Lion | 10 (25%) |
| Tiger | 10 (25%) |

**Attempts:**

As you can see, is a frequency table but with the big numbers smplified by thousands. I was trying to achieve my desired output with functions inside `gtsummary` like `style_number` but i keep recieving the error: Error in .x * scale : non-numeric argument to binary operator. The answer could also be in the r package `scales` (function: label_number).

Let me know if you have some insights. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `digits=` argument you can pass both integers AND styling functions. In the example below, I wrote a new function that scales large numbers to the nearest thousand.

Example!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.0'

style_number_10K <- function(x) paste0(style_number(x, scale = 0.001), "K")
style_number_10K(10002)
#> [1] "10K"

data <-
  data.frame(variable1 = rep(1:4, each = 10000)) %>%
  mutate(
    variable1 =
      dplyr::case_when(
        variable1 %in% 1 ~ "Dog",
        variable1 %in% 2 ~ "Cat",
        variable1 %in% 3 ~ "Lion",
        variable1 %in% 4 ~ "Tiger"
      )
  )

tbl <-
  data %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    digits = all_categorical() ~ list(style_number_10K, 0)
  )
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#all your code here

data %>% 
  tbl_summary() -> df

df$N <- gsub(",0+" , "" , df$N) # N here is the target column to format
```